# Error when adding illuminate/mail via composer

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, composer-php, lumen

I want to use email service in lumen, based on their [guide](http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/mail#configuration), I tried to add `illuminate/mail`package via composer by running following statement in command line.

```
composer require illuminate\mail
```

Now am getting following error,

```
[Invalid argument exception]
Could not find package illuminate\mail at any version for your minimum-stability (stable).Check package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

How can I resolve this? How can I use email service in Lumen?

Comment: As opposed to doing a composer require illuminate\mail, have you tried adding this dependency directly to the composer.json file and running composer install ?

Comment: but I dont know the version to add in composer.json.

Comment: I would think that you could throw in a wildcard and get what you want. I don't think it would hurt to test `1.*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using wrong slash it should be

```
composer require illuminate/mail
```